# How to use 'ifelse' and 'all' together?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

Hope I am not duplicating another's question and perhaps a similar vein to my other question.

I am trying to

1. Group the rows by `ID`
2. Then:
   a) assign 'A' to those who only have received product 'A'
   b) assign 'P' to those who only have received product 'P'
   c) assign 'A and P' to those who have received both products
   d) assign NA to those who have not received either A or P

My data `df`

```
df <- read.table(text =
"      ID Product
 1     1 A      
 2     1 A      
 3     1 A      
 4     2 NA     
 5     2 NA     
 6     3 P      
 7     3 P      
 8     4 A      
 9     4 P      
10     5 A      
11     6 P      
12     7 NA    ")
```

My desired output:

```
      ID Product Group

 1     1 A       A    
 2     1 A       A    
 3     1 A       A    
 4     2 NA      NA   
 5     2 NA      NA   
 6     3 P       P    
 7     3 P       P    
 8     4 A       A_P  
 9     4 P       A_P  
10     5 A       A    
11     6 P       P    
12     7 NA      NA
```

I've tried a few things, but the new column does not emerge:

```
df$Group <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  ifelse(all(df$Product==A), "A",
     ifelse(all(df$Product==P), "P",
            ifelse(all(df$Product==NA), "NA", "A_P") %>%
    ungroup()
```

I've also tried:

```
df$group <- df%>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  if(all(df$Product=="A") {
    df$group="A"
  } else if(all(df$Product=="P") {
      df$group="P"
  } else if(all(df$Product==NA) {
        df$group=NA
        }  else {df$group="A_P"}
```

But it keeps saying that my `}` is not supposed to be there which doesn't make sense to me?

My other question: Can you use `all` in `ifelse` statements for non-numerical vectors?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you expect the header of your new column to be?

Comment: Use `if (...) {...} else {...}` instead of `ifelse(..., ..., ...)`.

Comment: @DJ- new header = Group

Comment: Can you use `all` in `ifelse` statements for non-numerical vectors?

Comment: Your question has a clear statement of a problem, a reproducible example and a demonstration that you've already poked the problem a bit. Earns a +1 from me.

Comment: You shouldn't use `all` in `ifelse`. `ifelse` returns a vector of the same shape as the logical vector passed as the first argument. `all` returns a single logical value, so `ifelse` returns a single value.

Comment: You shouldn't use `else if ...` in R. It should be `else {if (...) {...}}`.

Comment: Thanks @RomanLuštrik for your upvote. Trying to improve… I couldn’t copy all my attempts as my R is running on a virtual desktop with no internet access!

Comment: @Roland- you’ve been super helpful. Can I ask if I correctly understood you meant by the ifelse and all answer? I’m relatively new to this. So all returns only ‘true’ or ‘false’ , but I am not sure about what you mean about ifelse only returning a single value when it can return 2 usually, but using if in this scenario is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ave`, avoiding if-else.

```
transform(df, Group=ave(Product, ID, FUN=\(x) {
  u <- paste(sort(unique(x)), collapse='_');replace(u, u == '', NA)}))
#    ID Product Group
# 1   1       A     A
# 2   1       A     A
# 3   1       A     A
# 4   2    <NA>  <NA>
# 5   2    <NA>  <NA>
# 6   3       P     P
# 7   3       P     P
# 8   4       A   A_P
# 9   4       P   A_P
# 10  5       A     A
# 11  6       P     P
# 12  7    <NA>  <NA>
```

maybe consider `toString` to make it comma-separated

```
transform(df, Group=ave(Product, ID, FUN=\(x) {
  u <- toString(sort(unique(x)));replace(u, u == '', NA)}))
#    ID Product Group
# 1   1       A     A
# 2   1       A     A
# 3   1       A     A
# 4   2    <NA>  <NA>
# 5   2    <NA>  <NA>
# 6   3       P     P
# 7   3       P     P
# 8   4       A  A, P
# 9   4       P  A, P
# 10  5       A     A
# 11  6       P     P
# 12  7    <NA>  <NA>
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L), Product = c("A", "A", "A", NA, NA, "P", "P", "A", "P", 
"A", "P", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

Comment: Hi! I am getting an error saying:  unexpected input in "transform(dummy, Group=ave(Product, ID, FUN=\

I don't know what \\(x) means- could you explain? I tried Googling but didn't come across something that helped.

Comment: @Jobolo Update your R, or use `function(x)` instead of `\(x)`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But is there an elegant way of adding this column to the original dataframe so I can see it on `View`?  Many thanks again!

Comment: It's actually accomplished by the code, just assign it back `df <- transform (...)`

Comment: I am a bit embarrassed for asking that, thanks for explaining that to me!

Comment: One more question, what does `;` mean? I tried Googling it but it did not come up where I looked.

Comment: This example worked well no matter the length of the value etc (e.g. in scenarios where the ID had an 'NA' and 'P' and 'A' value, the code was able to still discern that 'P' and 'A' were to be accounted for and generate the correct output.)

Comment: @Jobolo No worries, that's what the site is for. The semicolon `;` can be used to separate statements instead of a new line, see ["control structures"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Control-structures). I use it very sparingly because it's harder to read, but sometimes it's nice to make the code more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my stab using base R and a few readable lines of code. :)

```r
xy <- read.table(text =
                   "      ID Product
 1     1 A      
 2     1 A      
 3     1 A      
 4     2 NA     
 5     2 NA     
 6     3 P      
 7     3 P      
 8     4 A      
 9     4 P      
10     5 A      
11     6 P      
12     7 NA    ")

xygroup <- split(x = xy, f = xy$ID)

xy.withgroup <- lapply(X = xygroup, FUN = function(x) {
  unique.products <- unique(x$Product)
  if (all(is.na(unique.products))) {
    group <- NA
  } else {
    group <- paste(unique.products, collapse = "_")
  }
  
  x$Group <- group
  x
})

do.call(rbind, xy.withgroup)

    ID Product Group
1.1  1       A     A
1.2  1       A     A
1.3  1       A     A
2.4  2    <NA>  <NA>
2.5  2    <NA>  <NA>
3.6  3       P     P
3.7  3       P     P
4.8  4       A   A_P
4.9  4       P   A_P
5    5       A     A
6    6       P     P
7    7    <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: Nice one. Can I check- how do I get it to add a column to the dataframe? When I tried, it just joined the original datagrame with the .withgroup one. Many thanks!

Comment: @Jobolo not sure what you mean. The output contains the original input and the additional column. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Hi! What I mean is that it doesn't appear when I `View` the dataframe, however I think Rui Barradas below has clarified that all I need to do is to assign the result to a dataframe, I forgot about this :/

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @jay.sf:

```
df$Group <- tapply(df$Product, df$ID, \(x) { paste(sort(unique(x)), collapse = ' and ')})[df$ID]
df
#    ID Product   Group
# 1   1       A       A
# 2   1       A       A
# 3   1       A       A
# 4   2    <NA>      NA
# 5   2    <NA>      NA
# 6   3       P       P
# 7   3       P       P
# 8   4       A A and P
# 9   4       P A and P
# 10  5       A       A
# 11  6       P       P
# 12  7    <NA>      NA
```

Comment: Oooo nice one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a quite ugly solution using pivot_wider then paste0 to create a new data.table with your groups, then a right_join to put back the groups in your original dataset :

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text =
                   "      ID Product
 1     1 A      
 2     1 A      
 3     1 A      
 4     2 NA     
 5     2 NA     
 6     3 P      
 7     3 P      
 8     4 A      
 9     4 P      
10     5 A      
11     6 P      
12     7 NA    ")

df = df %>% mutate(Product2=Product)

df %>% mutate(ID=as.factor(ID)) %>% 
distinct(ID, Product, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, names_from = Product, values_from = Product2) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),~ifelse(is.na(.x),"",.x))) %>%
  mutate(Group=paste0(A, P)) %>%
  select(ID, Group) %>%
  right_join(df ,by="ID") %>%
  mutate(Group=ifelse(Group=="",NA,Group))%>%
  select(-Product2)
```

Feel free to ask any question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way. What your attempts are missing is that you must `mutate` the data set.
See also [Roland's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75862847/how-to-use-ifelse-and-all-together-r#comment133814227_75862847).

```r
df <- read.table(text =
                   "ID Product
 1     1 A      
 2     1 A      
 3     1 A      
 4     2 NA     
 5     2 NA     
 6     3 P      
 7     3 P      
 8     4 A      
 9     4 P      
10     5 A      
11     6 P      
12     7 NA", header = TRUE)

suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Group = if(length(unique(Product)) == 1L) Product else paste(Product, collapse = "_"))
#> # A tibble: 12 × 3
#> # Groups:   ID [7]
#>       ID Product Group
#>    <int> <chr>   <chr>
#>  1     1 A       A    
#>  2     1 A       A    
#>  3     1 A       A    
#>  4     2 <NA>    <NA> 
#>  5     2 <NA>    <NA> 
#>  6     3 P       P    
#>  7     3 P       P    
#>  8     4 A       A_P  
#>  9     4 P       A_P  
#> 10     5 A       A    
#> 11     6 P       P    
#> 12     7 <NA>    <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: How do you add a new column to the dataframe rather than it just printing out in the output? I tried and it just binds the new dataframe to the original one.

Comment: @Jobolo You must assign the result, for instance, `df2 <- df %>% rest of pipe`. Or, to add a new column to the original, `df <- df %>% rest of pipe`.

Comment: Oh yeah, this was a basic thing that I forgot. I really appreciate this, thanks @Rui Barradas